# Problem to gather privileges from server while using EVENTS(service provider say no possibility to On). Can I have any other possible option?

Tags: php, mysql

I was used events to insert my query to every hour finding average (that was calculated by the number of customer cames today and their respective total arrives from the beginning). Events successfully run and insert every hour needed values successfully on my localhost. But the main problem is to load the event into Server Db because our service provider refused to ON Superprivileges. Now I need to find another solution instead of event

this is my query on the event can we try any other way?

```
CREATE EVENT average_visiter
ON SCHEDULE
EVERY 1 DAY
STARTS '2014-04-30 00:20:00' ON COMPLETION PRESERVE ENABLE 
 DO
INSERT INTO `test_table`( `res_id`, `b_id`, `total_visit`, `tota_count`)  
SELECT res_id,b_id,sum(total_visit),count(cust_phone) FROM 
`customer_ledger` WHERE cust_phone IN (SELECT cust_phone FROM 
customer_ledger where DATE(last_visit)=CURRENT_DATE()-1) GROUP BY res_id,b_id
```

I need to put the same Insert query on any other way automatically. I don't have enough knowledge in triggers and stored procedure. Remember I need everyday details separately to show in the table

Answer (score 0):

I was used a trigger instead of Event

```
 USE feetobristo;
DELIMITER $$
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS feetobristo.customer_ledger_AFTER_INSERT$$
USE `feetobristo`$$
CREATE DEFINER=`feeto`@`localhost` TRIGGER feetobristo.customer_ledger_AFTER_INSERT 
AFTER INSERT ON customer_ledger FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
INSERT INTO test_table( res_id, b_id, total_visit, tota_count)  
SELECT res_id,b_id,sum(total_visit),count(cust_phone) FROM 
customer_ledger WHERE cust_phone IN (SELECT cust_phone FROM 
customer_ledger where DATE(last_visit)=CURRENT_DATE()) GROUP BY res_id,b_id;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

it was worked now fine ta-ta